# How to store setting with UWP C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I a'm running an uwp app on Rasbperry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IoT OS via Visual Studio Remote Machine and Release is selected.
The problem is how to save settings I have made and use the same settings when run same UWP app later.

How is it done? I can read the settings from the text file from 
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
But of course I can't save any changes to the same text file.
Where exactly should I put the text file if I wan't to save changes to text file?

But perhaps I can use this

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

But how do I check if there is no value stored and put instead an default value?

With this I am trying to save these settings it doesn't work. 
The point with this is that I can use these same settings when I run the same uwp app again.

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["setting1"] = textBlockDelayValue.Text;
localSettings.Values["setting2"] = checkShow;
```

Comment: SO Docs topic: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/uwp/5944/settings-and-app-data#t=201612170957559009768

Answer (score 0):

> Where exactly should I put the text file if I wan't to save changes to
>   text file?

You can put the text file in `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` of the solution and access it with this piece of code:

```
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    async void WriteFile()
    {
        StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt",
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "111");
    }

    async void ReadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
            String content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Timestamp not found
        }
    }
```

> But how do I check if there is no value stored and put instead an
>   default value?

You can read them out like this:

```
        var value1 = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["setting1"];
        var value2 = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["setting2"];
```